# Putting <dl> tag in my <p> tag?

Tags: xhtml, tags

I'm just learning xhtml and our teacher wants this quote in between our paragraph tags:

`"Definition lists are lists of terms and their definitions.  They are a little different than ordered and unordered lists in that the items are listed in pairs.  The dl and dl surround the list.  The name of the term appears between dt and dt, and the definition is between dd and dd."`

But my output looks like the one below when i put the tags in.  How can I put the <> around without making it interpret it as the definition tags???

`"Definition lists are lists of terms and their definitions.  They are a little different than ordered and unordered lists in that the items are listed in pairs.  The <dl> and </dl> surround the list.  The name of the term appears between<dt> and </dt>, and the definition is between <dd> and </dd>."`

Answer (score 1):

As you are aware, the characters `<`, `>`, and `&` have special meaning in (X)HTML. You can (and should) escape them by writing `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`, respectively.

See also [this article](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes), section "When to use escapes".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

"Definition lists are lists of terms and their definitions. They are a little different than ordered and unordered lists in that the items are listed in pairs. The < dl > and < dl > surround the list. The name of the term appears between < dt > and < dt >, and the definition is between < dd > and < dd >."